# What is a "councilmanic tax"?

Tags: united-states, voting, taxes, local-government

In my hometown there is an election next month for several propositions put forth. The second proposition would require any "new councilmanic tax" to be approved by the city council with a majority+1 vote.

The [voter's guide](http://www.spokanecity.org/_documents/election/2013-Special-Elections-Voters-Guide.pdf) for the election defines a councilmanic tax (in this case) to be:

> A tax for which the City Council has the authority to levy but has not
>   or is granted to the city council after March 1, 2013. A councilmanic
>   tax does not include fees, rates and charges, or special assessments
>   such a building permit fees, utility rates or LID assessments.

So, I take it that a councilmanic tax is one which the council had a legal right to levy but just had not up until now. Is this generally what the term "councilmanic tax" refers to?

I had never heard this term until I read the election ballot and I am curious about its implications and history. My hometown is in the USA, Washington State.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/councilmanic:

> Of or pertaining to a councilman or councilwoman, particularly to the district they represent.

Dictionary.com concurs.

Sounds to me merely like "a tax levied by the councilmen".

---

The clarification you quoted was NOT defining *councilmanic* taxes, but was (1) Defining taxes separate from other levies and (2) distinguishing OLD (pre-2013) taxes from NEW ones (it's very clear if you read the full voting guide here: http://c3.thevoterguide.org/v/tacoma12/race-detail.do?id=11203789 )

Comment: Thanks. Appears councilmanic is adjectivial, meaning what you said. The full voting guide link you provide is for an election in a different city (though it appears they have a prop similar to the one I am voting on).